# VSCode: Change Background Color of Unselected Occurrences

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I select some content, VSCode automatically highlights other occurrences like this:

[image]

In the above example, the `pass` in line 2 is the selected one while others are automatically highlighted. This is a really nice feature, but the problem is, the background color of those unselected occurrences is too close to that of selections. How can I change the background color for those unselected occurrences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The settings which will change backgorud is editor.selectionHighlightBackground. For changing background of highlighted similar words you should go to settings.json (**CTRL+SHIFT+P -> type settings.json**) of your theme and enter above code inside workbench.colorCustomizations.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations":{
        "editor.selectionBackground": "#013c53",
        "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#ff0000"
}
```

Comment: it works, but whenever I place my text cursor over a semantic (?) keyword like return/this/object key it gets highlighted with the (very slightly dimmed) selectionBackround color. This makes it almost impossible to distinguish between selected text and highlighted text. Who made this decision at vscode?